# ActiveMQ-Artemis 2.6 Set queue dead letter address using JMS management API

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm trying to set the dead letter address for a queue via the JMS management API.  From reading the latest Artemis docs it appears that I should be able to do this using the QueueControl.setDeadLetterAddress(...) method.  See https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/management.html and search for "setDeadLetterAddress".

It is my understanding that the parameters of these methods should be found in the Artemis QueueControl javadocs here: 
 https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html

However, that documentation does not have any mention of a setDeadLetterAddress method or what parameters is might accept.

Does the QueueControl.setDeadLetterAddress method still exist and can it be called from the JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(...) method?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [QueueControlImpl](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/management/impl/QueueControlImpl.java) class code it is clear that the setDeadLetterAddress operation is no longer present.  An operation in the [ActiveMQServerControlImpl class](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/management/impl/ActiveMQServerControlImpl.java) named *addAddressSettings* does provide the capability to set the DLA for a queue (as well as plenty of other settings).

For example:

```
Queue managementQueue = ActiveMQJMSClient.createQueue("activemq.management");
Queue replyQueue = ActiveMQJMSClient.createQueue("management.reply");

JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext();
JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(replyQueue)) {
JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
producer.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);

// Using AddressSettings isn't required, but is provided
// for clarity.
AddressSettings settings = new AddressSettings()
        .setDeadLetterAddress(new SimpleString("my.messages.dla"))
        .setMaxDeliveryAttempts(5)
        .setExpiryAddress(new SimpleString("ExpiryAddress"))
        .setExpiryDelay(-1L) // No expiry
        .setLastValueQueue(false)
        .setMaxSizeBytes(-1) // No max
        .setPageSizeBytes(10485760)
        .setPageCacheMaxSize(5)
        .setRedeliveryDelay(500)
        .setRedeliveryMultiplier(1.5)
        .setMaxRedeliveryDelay(2000)
        .setRedistributionDelay(1000)
        .setSendToDLAOnNoRoute(true)
        .setAddressFullMessagePolicy(AddressFullMessagePolicy.PAGE)
        .setSlowConsumerThreshold(-1)  // No slow consumer checking
        .setSlowConsumerCheckPeriod(1000)
        .setSlowConsumerPolicy(SlowConsumerPolicy.NOTIFY)
        .setAutoCreateJmsQueues(true)
        .setAutoDeleteJmsQueues(false)
        .setAutoCreateJmsTopics(true)
        .setAutoDeleteJmsTopics(false)
        .setAutoCreateQueues(true)
        .setAutoDeleteQueues(false)
        .setAutoCreateAddresses(true)
        .setAutoDeleteAddresses(false);

Message m = context.createMessage();
JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(m, ResourceNames.BROKER, "addAddressSettings",
        "my.messages", 
        settings.getDeadLetterAddress().toString(),
        settings.getExpiryAddress().toString(),
        settings.getExpiryDelay(),
        settings.isLastValueQueue(),
        settings.getMaxDeliveryAttempts(),
        settings.getMaxSizeBytes(),
        settings.getPageSizeBytes(),
        settings.getPageCacheMaxSize(),
        settings.getRedeliveryDelay(),
        settings.getRedeliveryMultiplier(),
        settings.getMaxRedeliveryDelay(),
        settings.getRedistributionDelay(),
        settings.isSendToDLAOnNoRoute(),
        settings.getAddressFullMessagePolicy().toString(),
        settings.getSlowConsumerThreshold(),
        settings.getSlowConsumerCheckPeriod(),
        settings.getSlowConsumerPolicy().toString(),
        settings.isAutoCreateJmsQueues(),
        settings.isAutoDeleteJmsQueues(),
        settings.isAutoCreateJmsTopics(),
        settings.isAutoDeleteJmsTopics(),
        settings.isAutoCreateQueues(),
        settings.isAutoDeleteQueues(),
        settings.isAutoCreateAddresses(),
        settings.isAutoDeleteAddresses());
producer.send(managementQueue, m);

Message response = consumer.receive();
// addAddressSettings returns void but this will also return errors if the
// method or parameters are wrong.
log.info("addAddressSettings Reply: {}", JMSManagementHelper.getResult(response));
```